# cakephp - form for belongsTo Model

Tags: database, forms, cakephp, model

I createt the following model to link 2 relational tables:

```
    class Ficha extends AppModel {

    //public $useTable = 'ficha_seg';

    var $primaryKey = 'id_ficha';

    var $name = 'Ficha';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Perigo' => array(
            'className'    => 'Perigo',
            'foreignKey'   => false,
            'conditions' => 'Perigo.id_fichas = Ficha.id_ficha'
        )
    );
}
```

Now, i have a form that requires data from the class Ficha, and then is redirected to another ctp page where i will input the data for the table "Perigos". However, since i'm still a newbie in cakephp i'm having difficult building that second form to insert the data on the table "Perigos". Here goes the code i built at the moment related to the second form:

FichasController.php (the method where is it supposed to save the data on the table "Perigos":

```
public function preencher_ficha(){

if ($this->request->is('ficha')) {
        $this->Ficha->create();

    if ($this->Ficha->Perigo->save($this->request->data)) {
        $last_id=$this->Ficha->getLastInsertID();
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated '.$last_id.'.');
        //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'preencher_ficha'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to qualquer coisa your post.');
    }
}   
}
```

The preencher_ficha.ctp file with the form:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Ficha->Perigo', array('action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('class_subst', array('label' => 'Classificação:'));
echo $this->Form->input('simbolos_perigo', array('label' => 'Símbolos:'));
echo $this->Form->input('frases_r', array('label' => 'Frases:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Finalizar Ficha');
```

Here i guess the create part is wrong, but i think i have errors too in the controller part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to structure your views in other way.
If you want to save data in the `Perigos` table, then use the `save` method of `PerigosController` and use the `save.ctp` file at Perigos view to show the form you want to use.

Anyway, if you want to do it in your way, your form should point to the `preencher_ficha` function to submit the data:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Ficha->Perigo', array('action' => 'preencher_ficha'));
```

Also, you have to change this:

```
if ($this->request->is('ficha')) {
```

To this

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
```

This is just a way to check if the data comes from the POST method or from the GET one.

And, just an advise: dont use the spanish names for controllers or models. If you use the english ones it will be more simple to follow CakePHP naming convention, it will make more sense and it will save you some time.

Comment: Sorry the late reply. But i don't have a PerigosController, should i have one? Since i'm using a $belongsTo, i guess i should just do everything on FichaController...

Comment: Every model should have a controller if you want to do work in the proper way. Basic function such as add, delete, edit should be there almost always. It makes things more simple.

Comment: Understood Steve, but now please explain-me somethin i'm not understanding until now. You said to use the save method in PerigosController and create a save.ctp file on the folder Viem of Perigos. Until now it's ok. But what i don't get it is:
I'm in a form of my Ficha Model. After submiting the data of that form to the db, i want to redirect to a page with another form that is related to the Model "Perigo". But how i do this? How i "redirect" to a model to another, so that after i submit the data of ficha i can jump to the model and controller "Perigo". That's what i still didn't understand.

Comment: Open a new question for that, I will try to understand what you mean. It is more difficult to answer here.

Comment: Well, anyway, once you submit the Ficha form, you can save the Ficha in your `save` action at your FichasController. Then, you can redirect the user to the Perigo view: `$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'perigos', 'action' => 'add'));` and that will show the `add.ctp` view of Perigo, where you will show the other form. Once the user submit this, it will go to the `add` action inside the `if ($this->request->is('post')) {` statement.

Comment: So once i do this: redirect(array('controller'=>'perigos', 'action' => 'add')); i will be under the Perigo Model right?

Comment: You will be redirected to the `perigos` controller which is automatically linked to the `perigos` model with `$this->Perigo`.

Comment: Ok, i guess that's what i'm looking for, i have to go lunch now, but i will try after it. Thanks Steve!